# Accidentally asking for dua I don’t want in my mind

Tags: dua

It’s been a few days now I’ve been wanting something from Allah but then I’m getting these thoughts that are exactly the opposite of what I want. Will the negative duas be accepted? I don’t want them to but I’m worrying.

Answer (score 0):

Well , I think this is a problem less related to Islam and more related to psychology , what you are experiencing is called intrusive thoughts , which happens in all general fields of life , like imagining yourself hurting someone you love , doing something extremely bad and having thoughts that you don't want to have .
Islam doesn't account for thoughts , like if you think of cursing someone and then refrain , it isn't considered a sin , similarly , whatever your thoughts are , if you haven't explicitly said them in Dua then you needn't worry , as for the intrusive thoughts , I believe this video might prove to be helpful :

- [How to deal with intrusive thoughts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=laeYq51SYA0)